# Finding $\,\%\,$ of salary relative to another salary

Tags: arithmetic

Sam makes $\$65$ per week and Don makes $\$138$ per week.

How do I express, as a percentage, how much more Don makes per week than Sam does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\text{Don earns}\;\;\left(\frac{\text{Don's earnings}-\text{Sam's earnings}}{\text{Sam's earning's}}\; \times 100 \%\right) \;\;\text{more than what Sam earns}$$

$$\dfrac {138 - 65}{65}\times 100\% \approx 112.31\%$$

This tells us that Don earns $\;\approx \;112.31\%\;$ *more than* Sam earns.

Comment: thanks a lot for showing me with detail. so the answer should be 112.31% ?

Comment: ok, thanks a lot for cleaning things out. I appreciate your help

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to help!

Comment: It is an English point, not a math point, but I would read "more than" as the difference over Sam's and get $112.31\%$

Comment: @RossMillikan: That's what I wrote at first (check edit history: first post). Perhaps I should include both?

Comment: I think the difference is that 105 is 5% more than 100, but is 105% of 100.  The more is the distinction.  I would do the first.